# Speech to text Conversion in MS BoT

Tags: c#, botframework

We want to have Speech to Text conversion implemented in MS Bot Framework. Is there any sample code I can review to understand how it should be implemented?

Our use case is like we can speak to BoT and this speech is converted to text then other functionalities like LUIS, AML integration etc is carried forward on the text.

Comment: In what language? C# or Node?

Comment: @EzequielJadib - doesn't matter what language. Questions asking for sample code / tutorials etc are expressly off-topic for StackOverflow. And there are plenty of samples available and findable through a search engine.

Comment: @EzequielJadib - C#

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [C# Speech To Text sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-SpeechToText) from the [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/) repository. In general, in that repo you will find plenty of samples about different features/capabilities of the framework.

I would strongly recommend you that from now on, take a look there first and then come to the forum.

Comment: This code is expecting a audio attachment file and then getting a Speech to Text conversion done. We are looking for a more In-Sync kind of BoT for example we build a BoT for say a car manufacturer and when user access this BoT and speak "Show me new car models" then this speech should be converted to text, then LUIS to understand Intent and then appropriate functionality to take over, every thing in Async.

Comment: It's doable too, using similar code and probably Skype as the channel